# Apache Ignite: sql query returns field with not declared class

Tags: java, ignite

Let's define "pojo" with single field of class `java.util.Date` acceptable for Ignite SQL queries:

```
public class TimeHolder {
  @QuerySqlField
  public Date date;

  public TimeHolder(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
  }
}
```

Now create ignite cache and query it via SQL:

```
    final IgniteCache<Integer, TimeHolder> timeCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(...);
    timeCache.put(1, new TimeHolder(new Date()));
    final FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> queryCursor = timeCache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select * from TimeHolder"));
    final List<?> timeHolderFields = queryCursor.iterator().next();
    final Object dateField = entityFields.iterator().next();
    assert theOnlyField.getClass() == java.sql.Timestamp.class;
```

It turns out, that `Object dateField` is not `java.util.Date` as declared but `java.sql.Timestamp`.

I guess holding date as `java.sql.Timestamp` somewhere in H2 internals helps handling SQL clauses. But why it is throwed outside instead of object of declared and expected class?

And a more important question is:
Where could I find reliable list of all these conversions?

UPDATE. Questions is answered in comment

Comment: I've found. * rty

Comment: I've found. 1) org.h2.value.DataType.getTypeFromClass returns int type for Class. In particular - 11 for java.util.Date 2) org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2RowDescriptor.wrap builds a org.h2.value.Value child depending on type from step 1. In particular, ValueTimestamp for type 11. 3) org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.twostep.GridMergeIndexIterator.advance calls Value.getObject that returns object depending on what child of Value it is. In particular, ValueTimestamp return java.sql.Timestamp

Answer (score 0):

`SqlQueryFields` returns SQL (JDBC) fields as opposed to fields of objects.

`java.util.Date` is not a JDBC type so it is converted. I'm not sure I will be able to find a complete list right away, but you can expect conversion or error for any types which don't have corresponding JDBC types.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `SqlQuery` (rather than a `SqlFieldsQuery`) you'll get the POJO as you're expecting. `SqlQuery` always returns a POJO, so you can't do things like joins and group by's.